# Com certeza ou concerteza?

Tags: gramática, ortografia

Vejo muitas pessoas escrevendo a palavra *concerteza* (que me parece incorreto), no entanto também já vi pessoas escrevendo *com certeza*, qual é o correto?

Comment: Esse é o erro número 1 da internet. Já fiz uma pesquisa sobre isso. Os outros são: apartir, agente, excessão, nada haver, derrepente, etc

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O correto, segundo a norma padrão da língua portuguesa, é "com certeza", separado. "Concerteza" é um erro um tanto comum de ortografia.

"Com certeza" indica que há a certeza do que se está falando, fundamentado em um fato. É sinônimo de "sem dúvida".

> — 2+2 = 4. Você considera correto esse resultado?
>   — Sim, **com certeza**!

Como também pode significar algo em que se tem certeza, mas que não necessariamente é um fato, como uma suposição ou probabilidade com grandes chances de serem de fato verdadeiras, segundo o orador. Sinônimo de "provavelmente". Usando a [frase de exemplo](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/63/com-certeza-ou-concerteza#comment-2239) do colega Centaurus abaixo:

> "Giovana está demorando muito a chegar", disse a mãe preocupada.
>   O pai então respondeu:
>   "Ah, **com certeza** ela passou na casa da Mariana, como já o fez em outras vezes."

Geralmente, de maneira informal, e ao menos no Brasil, "com certeza" nesse sentido tem o "com" omitido e o "que" adicionado, como em:

> — **Certeza que** ela passou na casa da Mariana.

Mas que também é utilizado por algumas pessoas até mesmo sem o "que".

Comment: Em português acontece sim: girassol (gira+sol), planalto (plano+alto), aguardente (água+ardente), etc

Comment: Corrigido. Especifiquei em que categoria de palavras isso não acontece.

Comment: Bruno, "com certeza" também é muito usado no sentido de "sem certeza" ou melhor "provavelmente".   ex.  "Giovana está demorando muito a chegar", disse a mãe preocupada. O pai então respondeu "Ah, **com certeza** ela passou na casa da Mariana, como já o fez em outras vêzes."   Aqui na minha casa usa-se muito "com certeza" com esse significado.  :-)

Comment: @Centaurus Complementei a resposta, obrigado. =)